# how to display alert box with Bootbox js plugin

Tags: jquery, alert

i have written a php code…

// If click check the session is set or not

```
if(isset($_POST['reserve'])){ if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){
$db->query(“INSERT INTO `reserve` (`r_b_id`,`r_m_id`,`r_date`) VALUES 
(‘$book_id’,'$userId’,'$date’)”);
}else{
echo ‘ ‘; // I nee to display alert box here }}
```

if session not start alert message should be displayed. how can i do it? i tried like this. but it didn’t work.

```
if(isset($_POST['reserve'])){
if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){
$db->query(“INSERT INTO `reserve` (`r_b_id`,`r_m_id`,`r_date`) VALUES         (‘$book_id’,'$userId’,'$date’)”);
}else{
echo ‘$(document).load(function(){
bootbox.alert(“You must login first”);
```

this is the link of bootbox site... http://bootboxjs.com/#usage

this is my full code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Book Detail</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../common/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php


    // Run the query to get each books detail.
    $db->query("SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `b_id` = '$book_id'");

    foreach($db->resultsArray as $row){
        echo "Id : ". $row['b_id'] . "<br />";
        echo "Category : ". $row['b_cat_id'] . "<br />";    
        echo "Title : ". $row['b_title'] . "<br />";    
        echo "Author : ". $row['b_author'] . "<br />";  
        echo "Summery : ". $row['b_summary'] . "<br />";    
    }

    // To get member id of loged in user's
    $db->query("SELECT `userId` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    $userId = $db->resultsArray['0']['userId'];

    // Get system date
    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    // Check reserve book button
    // If click check the session is set or not
    if(isset($_POST['reserve'])){
        if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){

            $db->query("INSERT INTO `reserve` (`r_b_id`,`r_m_id`,`r_date`) VALUES ('$book_id','$userId','$date')");

        }else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).load(function(){ bootbox.alert("You must login first");})</script>';
        }   
    }

?>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="submit" name="reserve" class="btn" id="reserve" value="Reserve Book" />
</form>

<!-- JS dependencies --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../common/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<!-- bootbox code --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/v2.4.2/bootbox.min.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any js errors? You may need to load jQuery in <head>.

Comment: Exactly it won't work until you put jquery in head. You will have to load jquery library first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
echo '$(document).load(function(){ bootbox.alert(“You must login first”);})';
```